# how to capture the string that beginning and ending certain kind of string with Regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
'\u001b[1m\u001b[31m  \u001b[1m● \u001b[1mregister page › register-automated › desktop › CONTROL\u001b[39m\u001b[22m\n\n    Expected image to match or be a close match to snapshot but was 0.009980258828690502% different from snapshot (91 differing pixels).\n    \u001b[1m\u001b[31mSee diff for details:\u001b[39m\u001b[22m \u001b[31m/src/pages/__image_snapshots__/__diff_output__/register-test-js-register-page-register-automated-desktop-control-1-diff.png\u001b[39m\n\u001b[2m\u001b[22m\n\u001b[2m    \u001b[0m \u001b[90m 60 | \u001b[39m\u001b[0m\u001b[22m\n\u001b[2m    \u001b[0m \u001b[90m 61 | \u001b[39m          \u001b[36mconst\u001b[39m image \u001b[33m=\u001b[39m await page\u001b[33m.\u001b[39mscreenshot({ fullPage\u001b[33m:\u001b[39m isFullPage })\u001b[33m;\u001b[39m\u001b[0m\u001b[22m\n\u001b[2m    \u001b[0m\u001b[31m\u001b[1m>\u001b[2m\u001b[39m\u001b[90m 62 | \u001b[39m          expect(image)\u001b[33m.\u001b[39mtoMatchImageSnapshot({threshold\u001b[33m:\u001b[39m \u001b[35m0.3\u001b[39m})\u001b[33m;\u001b[39m\u001b[0m\u001b[22m\n\u001b[2m    \u001b[0m \u001b[90m    | \u001b[39m                        \u001b[31m\u001b[1m^\u001b[2m\u001b[39m\u001b[0m\u001b[22m\n\u001b[2m    \u001b[0m \u001b[90m 63 | \u001b[39m        })\u001b[33m;\u001b[39m\u001b[0m\u001b[22m\n\u001b[2m    \u001b[0m \u001b[90m 64 | \u001b[39m\u001b[0m\u001b[22m\n\u001b[2m    \u001b[0m \u001b[90m 65 | \u001b[39m        \u001b[36mif\u001b[39m(experimentName \u001b[33m||\u001b[39m experiementVariationName) {\u001b[0m\u001b[22m\n\u001b[2m\u001b[22m\n\u001b[2m      \u001b[2mat Object.toMatchImageSnapshot (\u001b[2msrc/command/getPageImageShot.js\u001b[2m:62:25)\u001b[2m\u001b[22m\n'
```

how to capture `/src/pages/__image_snapshots__/__diff_output__/register-test-js-register-page-register-automated-desktop-control-1-diff.png` from this gibberish?

I tried `.match(/\bdetails\.\w+png\b/)` for capture all the string between the end of `...detail:` and end of `.png` string, but it did not went well, just kept return `null`. I want to do this way, is because everything after `See diff for details:` and before `.png` can be different text...

Comment: Try matching `\/src\/.*?\.png\b` https://regex101.com/r/8NKlun/1 If you want `details` in the match you could use a capturing group for the part you are looking for `\bdetails:.*?(\/src\/.*?\.png\b)`  https://regex101.com/r/8NKlun/2/

Comment: `/\bdetails\.\w+png\b/` you expect a literal dot after `details` and there is actually a `:`.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I just want the path in the end result, the whole text `See diff for details:` should not be part of the result. sorry my description maybe a bit confusing...

Comment: @VLAZ hope above also clarified for you

Comment: @Ezeewei The value (the path only) is in the first capturing group. See the green highlight https://regex101.com/r/8NKlun/2/

Comment: @Ezeewei I was saying that the pattern you defined doesn't match the data you have. Hence why it doesn't work. It will never match anything because of the `.` vs `:` disparity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a capturing group to get the path and add a colon `:` after details

```
\bdetails:.*?(\/.*?\.png\b)
```

- `\bdetails:` Match word boundary and `details:`
- `.*?` Match any char 0+ times non greedy (If there are no forward slashes in between, you could also use a negated character class `[^\/]*`
- `(` Capture group

  - `\/.*?\.png\b` Match any char non greedy and `.png` and word boundary
- `)` Close capturing group

In the replacement use `$1/`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tNKR1k/1)

```js
const regex = /\bdetails:.*?(\/.*?\.png\b)/;
const str = `'\\u001b[1m\\u001b[31m  \\u001b[1m● \\u001b[1mregister page › register-automated › desktop › CONTROL\\u001b[39m\\u001b[22m\\n\\n    Expected image to match or be a close match to snapshot but was 0.009980258828690502% different from snapshot (91 differing pixels).\\n    \\u001b[1m\\u001b[31mSee diff for details:\\u001b[39m\\u001b[22m \\u001b[31m/src/pages/__image_snapshots__/__diff_output__/register-test-js-register-page-register-automated-desktop-control-1-diff.png\\u001b[39m\\n\\u001b[2m\\u001b[22m\\n\\u001b[2m    \\u001b[0m \\u001b[90m 60 | \\u001b[39m\\u001b[0m\\u001b[22m\\n\\u001b[2m    \\u001b[0m \\u001b[90m 61 | \\u001b[39m          \\u001b[36mconst\\u001b[39m image \\u001b[33m=\\u001b[39m await page\\u001b[33m.\\u001b[39mscreenshot({ fullPage\\u001b[33m:\\u001b[39m isFullPage })\\u001b[33m;\\u001b[39m\\u001b[0m\\u001b[22m\\n\\u001b[2m    \\u001b[0m\\u001b[31m\\u001b[1m>\\u001b[2m\\u001b[39m\\u001b[90m 62 | \\u001b[39m          expect(image)\\u001b[33m.\\u001b[39mtoMatchImageSnapshot({threshold\\u001b[33m:\\u001b[39m \\u001b[35m0.3\\u001b[39m})\\u001b[33m;\\u001b[39m\\u001b[0m\\u001b[22m\\n\\u001b[2m    \\u001b[0m \\u001b[90m    | \\u001b[39m                        \\u001b[31m\\u001b[1m^\\u001b[2m\\u001b[39m\\u001b[0m\\u001b[22m\\n\\u001b[2m    \\u001b[0m \\u001b[90m 63 | \\u001b[39m        })\\u001b[33m;\\u001b[39m\\u001b[0m\\u001b[22m\\n\\u001b[2m    \\u001b[0m \\u001b[90m 64 | \\u001b[39m\\u001b[0m\\u001b[22m\\n\\u001b[2m    \\u001b[0m \\u001b[90m 65 | \\u001b[39m        \\u001b[36mif\\u001b[39m(experimentName \\u001b[33m||\\u001b[39m experiementVariationName) {\\u001b[0m\\u001b[22m\\n\\u001b[2m\\u001b[22m\\n\\u001b[2m      \\u001b[2mat Object.toMatchImageSnapshot (\\u001b[2msrc/command/getPageImageShot.js\\u001b[2m:62:25)\\u001b[2m\\u001b[22m\\n'`;
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$1/"));
```

Thanks to [@VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz) helping solving the issue.

Comment: You can also strip away the shell formatting codes and leave everything else. This is in case the URL doesn't start with `/scr`. [Shell formatting codes](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting) start with `\e` or `\033` or `\x1B` and then are followed by the text control information such as colour or effect to apply. [SuperUser.SE has more details on how to match them](https://superuser.com/questions/380772/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-text-stream).

Comment: @VLAZ That is also a nice approach. Thanks for link, I will take a look.

Comment: actually @VLAZ got a good point... if the `src` is not there, then the whole regex is invalid, no?

Comment: allowing the part after `:` to be different is pretty important... hum....

Comment: @Ezeewei indeed. Although it could be correct if `src` is dropped and it only checks for `/`. Unless the URL can also start with something different like `http://google.com` or maybe just straight up doesn't have a forward slash: `src/pages/`.

Comment: @Ezeewei If what follows after is a path like structure, you could omit /src/ and start the match with `\bdetails:[^\/]+(\/[^\/]+\/.*?\.png\b)` https://regex101.com/r/bBZA0A/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird oh boy... I was trying to just remove the `src` or replace it with just `/` the whole thing is done... is there something else it should be done so that the focus will be only on the `/` before `src` instead of the text `src` itself?

Comment: @Ezeewei no, that should be enough. At least given the data you've shown here - there are no other occurrences of `/` before the path shows up, so if you literally just remove `src` from the pattern it would still match the exact same thing.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I was thinking like this: https://regex101.com/r/bBZA0A/3 - I dropped `src\/` - didn't realise there was a slash after it, for some reason. But my idea was the same - capture from `/` to `png`

Comment: @Thefourthbird, yea VLAZ one did it. thank you both for the help!! extremely helpful.

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ! really appreciate the modification

Comment: @VLAZ That is also possible, the other way around.

Comment: @VLAZ Should I update the post or are you posting it?

Comment: @Thefourthbird eh, go for it. I'm going to bed any minute now, so I don't feel like posting a full answer.

Comment: Ok, @Thefourthbird I marked your answer to be best answer now. feel free to update your answer to VLAZ now, thank you all for the help!

Comment: @Thefourthbird you may also want to udpate the demo after "See a regex demo" since it is the src one still. thanks!